# How can an author be subscribed to the posts of another author and receive notifications of the new posts?

Tags: author, front-end, notifications

What I'm trying to achieve is to implement a function that will enable an author, when registered and browsing the front-end, to have the option of following other authors of the site and receiving notifications via a front end message when the followed authors post. Is this something that can be achieved with WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [WP Subscribe Author plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subscribe-author/) which does the job.

I did some tweaking to the email that is sent in the PHP file as the default email didn't include a link to the post.

Comment: it seems that the plugin is abandoned now.. too bad, i really need this.